# Hierarchical Forecasting using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, hierarchical, fable-r

I am using fable package to forecast for hierarchical time series and depth of all nodes is not equal.
Use case is, forecasting contacts at country -> state -> district level. Forecast values have to add up to country level when aggregated (lower-level forecasts equate to the upperlevel forecasts.)

https://robjhyndman.com/papers/Foresight-hts-final.pdf
Given below is the code i tried and while forecasting on test data.

```
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# selecting train data
train_df <- tourism %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) <= 2014 & Region %in% c("MacDonnell", "Melbourne"))

# selecting test data
test_df <- tourism %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) > 2014 & Region %in% c("MacDonnell", "Melbourne"))

# fitting ets model with reconcilliation
ets_fit <- train_df %>%
  aggregate_key(Purpose * (State / Region), Trips = sum(Trips)) %>%
  model(ets=ETS(Trips)) %>%
  reconcile(ets_adjusted = min_trace(ets))
# forecasting on test data
fcasts_test <- forecast(ets_fit, test_df)
```

Getting error as

```
Error: Provided data contains a different key structure to the models.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: While you may be comfortable with Python, this question doesn't have anything to do with Python, does it?

Comment: @mkrieger1, it doesn't i was open to solution either in Python/R that is the reason i mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the key structure using `aggregate_key()` before fitting the model, so the forecast key structure does not match the test set. You will need to create the test set *after* using `aggregate_key()`.

However, you cannot filter by one of the keys after creating aggregates, because then the aggregate information is incomplete.

Here is an example that does what you want.

```r
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Aggregate data as required
agg_tourism <- tourism %>%
  filter(Region %in% c("MacDonnell", "Melbourne")) %>%
  aggregate_key(Purpose * (State / Region), Trips = sum(Trips))

# Select training data
train_df <- agg_tourism %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) <= 2014)

# Select test data
test_df <- agg_tourism %>%
  filter(year(Quarter) > 2014)

# Fit ets model with reconcilliation
ets_fit <- train_df %>%
  model(ets = ETS(Trips)) %>%
  reconcile(ets_adjusted = min_trace(ets))
# forecasting on test data
fcasts_test <- forecast(ets_fit, test_df)

fcasts_test
#> # A fable: 600 x 7 [1Q]
#> # Key:     Purpose, State, Region, .model [50]
#>    Purpose  State              Region     .model Quarter      Trips .mean
#>    <chr*>   <chr*>             <chr*>     <chr>    <qtr>     <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2015 Q1 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  2 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2015 Q2 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  3 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2015 Q3 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  4 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2015 Q4 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  5 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2016 Q1 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  6 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2016 Q2 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  7 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2016 Q3 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  8 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2016 Q4 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#>  9 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2017 Q1 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#> 10 Business Northern Territory MacDonnell ets    2017 Q2 N(5.1, 21)  5.12
#> # … with 590 more rows

fcasts_test %>%
  filter(Region == "Melbourne", Purpose == "Visiting") %>%
  autoplot(agg_tourism)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>